# Let $A:\mathbb R_2[x]\rightarrow \mathbb R_2[x]$ is a linear transformation defined as $(A(p))(x)=p'(x+1)$. Find matrix of $(A(p))(x)$.

Tags: matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $A:\mathbb R_2[x]\rightarrow \mathbb R_2[x]$ is a linear transformation defined as $(A(p))(x)=p'(x+1)$ where $\mathbb R_2[x]$ is the space of polynomials of the second order. Find all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ such that the matrix $        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 1 & 0 \\
        b & 0 & 1 \\
        c & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix of linear transformation $A$ with respect to some arbitrary basis of $\mathbb R_2[x]$.

**EDIT**:

From the given matrix we have
$$[b_1]_{B'}=        \begin{bmatrix}
        a  \\
        b  \\
        c  \\
        \end{bmatrix},[b_2]_{B'}=        \begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix},[b_3]_{B'}=        \begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

where $B'$ is some basis different from standard basis.

Now, we have
$$b_1=a\cdot {b'}_1+b\cdot {b'}_2+c\cdot {b'}_3$$
$$b_2=1\cdot {b'}_1+0\cdot {b'}_2+0\cdot {b'}_3$$
$$b_3=0\cdot {b'}_1+1\cdot {b'}_2+0\cdot {b'}_3$$

From above equations,

$${b'}_1=x$$
$${b'}_2=x^2$$
$${b'}_3=\frac{1-ax-bx^2}{c},c\neq 0$$

Now we need to find the matrix of linear transformation $A$ with respect to basis $B'$.

Standard basis is $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$ and $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb R_2[x]$ in basis $B$.

Linear transformation is given by
$$(A(p))(x)=p'(x+1)=(2+b)+2cx+0x^2$$ in basis $B$.

In basis $B'$, we get       $\begin{bmatrix}
        a  & 1 & 0\\
        b  & 0 & 1\\
        c  & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
        2+b  \\
        2c  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}        =\begin{bmatrix}
        2a+ab+2c  \\
        2b+b^2  \\
        2c+bc  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Linear transformation $A$ in the new basis is given by
$$((A(p))(x))'=(2a+ab+2c)x+b(2+b)x^2+c(2+b)\frac{1-ax-bx^2}{c}$$
$$=(2a+ab+2c)x+b(2+b)x^2+(2+b)(1-ax-bx^2)$$

**Question**: For all $a,b$ and for all $c\neq 0$, the matrix given by $        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 1 & 0 \\
        b & 0 & 1 \\
        c & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix of linear transformation $A$ in some basis $B'$.

Is this correct?

Comment: In $any$ basis, $T$ is determined by its effect on the basis vectors. So let your basis be $\left \{ p_1,p_2,p_3 \right \}$ and now....

Comment: See [Companion Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) (you should transpose the one in the link, though).

Comment: From $p(x)=\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2$, one gets $p'(x)=\beta +2\gamma x$ and so $p'(x+1)=2\gamma x+(2+\beta)$, therefore $A(p(x))=2\gamma x+(2+\beta)$, which is completely different from what you got. Also your computations for $A(1),A(x)$ and $A\left(x^2\right)$ are wrong.