# Let $A:\mathbb R_2[x]\rightarrow \mathbb R_2[x]$ is a linear transformation defined as $(A(p))(x)=p'(x+1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A:\mathbb R_2[x]\rightarrow \mathbb R_2[x]$ is a linear transformation defined as $(A(p))(x)=p'(x+1)$ where $\mathbb R_2[x]$ is the space of polynomials of the second order. Find all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ such that the matrix $        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 1 & 0 \\
        b & 0 & 1 \\
        c & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix of linear transformation $A$ with respect to some arbitrary basis of $\mathbb R_2[x]$.

Any solution would be much appreciated

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716262/let-a-mathbb-r-2x-rightarrow-mathbb-r-2x-is-a-linear-transformation-defi?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For a basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ of $\Bbb R_2[x]$, the $i$th column of the matrix of $A$ is just $Ae_i$, coordinated by the coefficients of $e_1,e_2,e_3$. 
Specifically here, based on the 2nd and 3rd columns, we want such an $e_1,e_2,e_3$, for which  $Ae_2=e_1$ and $Ae_3=e_2$.

> So, just pick an arbitrary quadratic $e_3\in\Bbb R_2[x]$, and this will give you $e_2$ and $e_1$ by the above, and you will also obtain $a,b,c$ when calculating $Ae_1$.

Comment: So, did you successfully arrive to $a=b=c=0$ (as the differential of a constant function is zero)?

Comment: I've managed to prove that $a=b=0$ but I couldn't prove that $c=0$.
Since $Ae_1=A_{*1}$ and since $Ae_1,Ae_2,Ae_3$ must be linearly independent (because $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are) I've managed to respresent $Ae_1=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0  & c
\end{bmatrix}^T$